# What is the Householder matrix for complex vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

For $\Bbb R^n$, Householder matrix $Q=I-2vv^T$ is an operator that maps a vector to its reflection across a hyperplane of normal $v$.

> The following is an illustration for Householder operator of a general inner product space.
>   [image]
>
> For $\Bbb R^n$, use standard inner product, then we have $x-2<x,v>v=x-2vv^Tx=(I-2vv^T)x$, where $I-2vv^T$ is the Householder matrix. It satisfies the following
>   [image]

However, I am wondering what would be the Householder matrix for complex vector space $\Bbb C^n$? It looks like $I-2vv^H$ is not right ($H$ denotes conjugate transpose), because by my calculation it does not satisfy above problem 5.7.3. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) suggests

> [image]

I tried, and I might be wrong, but it does not seem to satisfy problem 5.7.3 either.

> $Q(x+y)=(x + y) - \frac{{x - y}}{{{{\left\| {x - y} \right\|}^2}}}({(x - y)^H}(x + y) + \frac{{{x^H}(x - y)}}{{{{(x - y)}^H}x}}{(x - y)^H}(x + y))$
>
> It looks impossible for $Q(x+y)=x+y$ unless $x^Hy=y^Hx$.

Comment: the formula (and the text on the graph) is not totally correct. It must be $$Q(x):=x-2\langle x,v\rangle v/\|v\|$$ what simplifies if $\|v\|=1$. In the graph you must change $\|v\|$ by $\|x\|$.

Answer (score 2):

Take a vector $w \in\mathbb C^n$. The Householder matrix $U_w$ is be defined as
$$U_w := I - \frac{2}{w^*w}ww^*$$
where $^*$ denotes hermitian adjoint.

However, complex householder matrices don't have the "reflector" property that real hoseholder matrices has, and is shown in Problem 5.7.3 in your question.

The closest we get, is making sure that it goes in one way. Theorem 2.1.13 from Horn & Johnson Matrix Analysis 2nd ed (2012) presents just this. They explicitly construct a matrix $U(y, x)$ with the property $U(y, x)x = y$, and that coincides with a real householder matrix when possible..

> **Theorem 2.1.13.** Let $x, y ∈ \mathbb C^n$ be given and suppose that $||x|| = ||y|| > 0$. If $y = e^{iθ} x$ for some real $θ$, let $U(y, x) = e^{iθ} I_n$; otherwise, let $φ ∈ [0, 2π)$ be such that
> $x^* y = e^{iφ}||x^*y||$ (take $φ = 0$ if $x^*y = 0$); let $w = e^{iφ}x − y$; and let $U(y, x) = e^{iφ}U_w$,
> in which $U_w = I − \frac{2}{w^*w}ww^*$
> is a Householder matrix.

Then $U(y, x)$ is unitary and essentially Hermitian, $U(y, x)x = y$, and $U(y, x)z ⊥ y $ whenever $z ⊥ x$. If $x$ and $y$ are real, then $U(y, x)$ is real orthogonal: $U(y, x) = I$ if $y = x$, and $U(y, x)$ is the
real Householder matrix $U_{x−y}$ otherwise.

Comment: Follow-up question: If we had x and y as complex vectors and $||x||_2 = ||y||_2$, then would you know how to go about finding a complex scalar, $\delta$, if we have $H := H( x - \delta y)$ and want $Hx = \delta y$ ?

Comment: What is $H$ in the question?

Comment: Oh, sorry for not being more specific! For any complex vector $v$, $H(v) = I - \frac{2vv^*}{v^*v}$. Using your notation, $H(w) = U_w$

Comment: ok. im not familiar with that problem from before. sorry. but I imagine you can solve that algebraically by plugging in definitions and solving the equations.

Comment: I ending solving for $\delta$. In case you were interested, $\delta = \frac{(y^*) x}{|(x^*) y|}$. This value of delta will make $U_{x - \delta y} x = \delta y$