# Differences between real and complex Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I recently noticed that my go-to reference for stuff related to Hilbert spaces uses the terms "Hilbert space" and "complex Hilbert space" synonymously. Hence the following questions:

- Are there any "basic" theorems that only hold in the complex (or the real) case? By "basic" I perhaps mean that they would be discussed in introductory functional analysis courses.
- In particular, what about spectral theory and functional calculus? What motivates the restriction to the complex case?
- Any general guidelines/rules of thumb to quickly evaluate whether a result only holds for complex/real spaces? E.g. some feature in the statement of the theorem or something to look for in the proof.

Comment: $\langle Tx, x \rangle=0$ for all $x$ implies $T=0$ (for a bounded operator $T$) in the case of Complex HS but not in the case of a real HS.

Comment: See also e.g. [Unitary operators and a product of reflections](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4804024/unitary-operators-and-a-product-of-reflections/), where every unitary on a real vector space is a product of appropriately defined "reflections," but the operators defined analogously on a complex vector space do not do this (and indeed, behave less like "reflections"). The answer there links to another question with more discussion of the topic. (As with geetha's example, the difference can be regarded as arising from symmetry vs. conjugate symmetry in the inner product)

Comment: Spectral theory basically fails completely in the real case, because the spectrum could be empty. Indeed, even for matrices real matrices could have no eigenvalue, which cannot happen for complex matrices. This basically means functional calculus wouldn’t make sense either. (Especially the holomorphic functional calculus, which, of course, already refers to the quintessential complex concept of holomorphic functions.)

Comment: Most theorems about the geometry of spaces, or things about linear functionals, basically hold for both real and complex cases. Spectral theory basically holds only for complex ones. Most of the theory for operators on Hilbert spaces was developed for complex Hilbert spaces, though some results hold for real Hilbert spaces as well - this really depends on whether the result is more analytic/geometric in nature or more spectral theory/operator algebraic in nature, with the former more likely to hold for real spaces and the latter less likely.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my favorite result, which is true in the real case ($\mathbb K = \mathbb R$), but fails in the complex case ($\mathbb K = \mathbb C$): The map $f \colon H \to \mathbb K$, $x \mapsto \|x\|_H^2/2$ is (Fréchet) differentiable.